# Firebase Firestore running twice inside react useEffect() hook. Why?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

I have connected to my Firebase Firestore database in useEffect() hook in react-native. My useEffect looks like this -

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("HEY")
        firestore().collection('users')
        .doc('user1').get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            console.log("SNAPSHOT",snapshot.data())
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
```

Now my logs look like these:

[image: LOGS]

Clearly "HEY" is console logged once whereas "SNAPSHOT ..." is console logged twice with the same data. Why? Also am I charged twice for two SNAPSHOTS or my second snapshot is retrieved from my local cache, which means I am charge for one read only.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
  firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc("user1")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      console.log("SNAPSHOT", snapshot.data());
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}, [firestore]);
```

Don't forget to add the dependency array as the second argument to the useEffect hook

Comment: Thank you Aishwarye for the reply. But why did you pass [firestore] into the useffect(). Also if I at .then(snaphot) pass a redux action ( which means props will get updated), will I still have to pass [firestore]?

Comment: So you can remove firestore and just have an empty array. That would mean the code inside useEffect will run only once. However, it could be that the firestore instance you are using is not global ( let's say you have multiple instances of firestore with different configs) then adding firestore to the dependency array would take care that case also.

Comment: So useEffect will only run whenever firestore instance changes. For an empty dependency array,useEffect will only run once per component initialization. Having no dependency array means useEffect will run everytime the component updates.